# Except Select2 any other option for dropdown search

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

In my project student name shown dropdown with use **select2**.More student name in dropdown load in select2 time page load to be slow.So I try load another way show load data.I want know without **select2** any other way to dropdown with search option is available?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] as requested when you subscribed to stackoverflow. And then improve your question accordingly

Comment: SO is about helping developers with source code mainly.